# can't send nonce to Braintree

Tags: node.js, swift, braintree, nonce

I'm trying ti integrate with Brain tree sandbox,

I'm trying to send my nonce from the ios client to my server but I get this error in my console : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'payment_method_nonce' of undefined`

my server side code is :

```
app.post("/checkout", function (req, res) {
var nonceFromTheClient = req.body.payment_method_nonce;
gateway.transaction.sale({
amount: "10.00",
paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
options: {
  submitForSettlement: true
}
}, function (err, result) {
if (err) {
  print(err)
}
else if (result.success) {
  console.log(result);
}
});});
```

in my Ios side :

```
    func createTransaction(paymentMethodNonce:String) {
    let paymentURL = postUrl!
    var request = URLRequest(url: paymentURL)
    request.httpBody = "payment_method_nonce=\(paymentMethodNonce)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return}
        else {
            print(response)}
        }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'payment_method_nonce' of undefined`

This means your req.body is empty/not parsed. Did you import body-parser? This module will parse the body and make it available to you.

Comment: I'm not sure how i'm suppose to use this body-parser 
i declared this :` var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`
I'm having hard time to understand how to use it on my  `var nonceFromTheClient = req.body.payment_method_nonce;`

Comment: There is no need for you to use this module. The server uses this automatically to parse the data which you have passed in  the body and make it available for  you.

Comment: Also I would suggest you to send the body as a dictionary to the server.
Ex: dictionary["payment_method_nonce"] = paymentMethodNonce
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictonary, options: .prettyPrinted)

Comment: First import the body-parser module in your server code. Next try converting you post body to dictionary in swift. These two changes will help solve your issue